# How to clear search bar text when closing form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MainMenu with a search bar and two buttons. Button1 opens MainForm, Subform1, and Subform2 in VIEW only mode, filtered to the SchoolID typed into the unbound search bar.

My question is: When the user returns to the MainMenu by clicking my CloseFormOpenMainMenu button , how can I clear what is typed into the MainMenu search bar and clear the filter?

Here is my code on the MainMenu:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim txtSearchBar As String
Dim Cancel As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorBEDSIDSearch

DoCmd.OpenForm "MainForm", , , "SchoolID = " & ("""" & Me.txtSearchBar.Value 
& """"), acFormReadOnly  

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Here is my code on the MainForm:

```
Private Sub CloseFormOpenMainMenu_Click()

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainMenu"

End Sub
```

If it helps, I have the "Filter On Load" property = No and the "Filter" property is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to clear the textbox from the other form:

```
Forms("MainMenu").txtSearchBar.Value = Null
```

Implemented:

```
Private Sub CloseFormOpenMainMenu_Click()

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainMenu"
Forms("MainMenu").txtSearchBar.Value = Null

End Sub
```