# Built in control/function to clear text input when the form is close

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating multiple forms that have multiple textboxes in 1 form. I found that if I use Form1.Hide() the form only hide but the input didn't clear. So it will appear again if I open back.

When I search on the Internet, some of them suggest the [hardcode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197533/how-to-clear-search-bar-text-when-closing-form) while some suggest using [textbox.Clear()/textbox.text=""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754108/vb-net-clear-or-txtbox-text-textbox-clear-methods). I tried Dispose() but it just clear the junk resources in the program but not the input.

So does Visual Basic has built-in code for this function as I think that this is a common function...

Comment: You probably shouldn't be hiding the form in the first place. It's rare that doing so is a good idea and if you want to "clear" the form then it's almost guaranteed that you should not be. Most likely, you should be creating a new instance of that type and displaying it every time you need to display a form of that type. The new form will be clear by default, so no need to explicitly clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear a `TextBox` then you should call its `Clear` method. If you want to do that when a form is hidden then you should handle the `VisibleChanged` event, test that the `Visible` property is `False` and then call the method. If you want to do this for every `TextBox` on the form then you need to loop through all the `TextBoxes` on the form in the `VisibleChanged` event handler and call their `Clear` method. Assuming all `TextBoxes` are directly on the form, that might look like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.VisibleChanged
    If Not Visible Then
        For Each tb In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            tb.Clear()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to do that in multiple forms then you can create one form with that functionality and then have the others inherit that class instead of the standard `Form` class.